# Questions 'funnel' based on previous question's answers

Tags: php, wordpress

I am starting to build out a feature similar to a question funnel, and I want to avoid a quiz/question plugin if possible as they're a bit hacky.

Basically it'd work that there is an initial question, and depending on that answer, that will choose the 2nd question, and then depending on that answer will either show 1 of 2 questions and so on, until the final question and then will show some content to the user.

I was thinking of using ACF Pro and using a 'parent question' approach, but this doesn't allow me to show based on the answer, only the parent question.

- Questions based on the answers of the parent question
- If no child question(s), show the content of the answer above. Eg if 'not pregnant', show content, but if 'pregnant', then show next questions.

Thoughts? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use gravity form. In gravity form their is option to show conditions based if answer A means show Question 2.

Comment: example https://docs.gravityforms.com/enable-conditional-logic/

Comment: Have you already tried things ?

Comment: @St3an I am trying conditional logic with ACF/Gravity. Why? Did you have another approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your form without page reload, then you should, obviously, use javaScript/jQuery. However, it seems you're looking for a PHP solution. You can achieve this by sending and getting globals through form. Depending on that, you can do your logic.
Simple example:

```
<form action="/quiz-page-2" method="get">
    <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
    <label for="html">HTML</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
    <label for="css">CSS</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript">
    <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
    <button type="submit">Next page</button>
</form>
```

On the next page, quiz-page-2, you check for the answer

```
<?php
if($_GET['fav_language'] === 'HTML')
     // Another question...
if($_GET['fav_language'] === 'CSS')
     // Another question...
if($_GET['fav_language'] === 'JavaScript')
     // Another question...
```

If you will use GET method, answers will be visible in the URL, but if you want to keep URL clean, you can use POST method, then form method would be post, and you get your variables like this `$_POST['fav_language']`.

EDIT:

Option 2, without hard coding. It would require to install [ACF Multistep plugin](https://wpfavs.com/plugins/acf-multistep), there might be more plugins with similar approach.
You would start the Field group with the step field
[image]
And for the 2 question you would choose conditional logic, if some value, then show this field.
[image]
[Live example](https://owneroo.com/form/)

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for an actual Wordpress strategy on how to implement that kind of funnel-type logic, not how to hard code an if/else statement.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I thought you're building plugin yourself. I edited my answer with 2nd option, using ACF.

Comment: Thanks @Mantc, I forgot that ACF could do conditional logic based on the choice, I always thought it was based on the question (but now thinking about it more, that doesn't make much sense).